# How do I programmatically populate longitude and latitude fields when Geolocation used in content type

Tags: 8, nodes

I am using the Geolocation module and I have created a custom content type (we'll call it Bookshop), which contains a field called location and is of type Geolocation.

I can already programmatically create the custom content type instance and programmatically populate the title field.

```
    $node=Node::create(
      'title'=>'Shop 1'
    );

    $node->save();
```

How would I go about populating the the Geolocation field content (e.g. the longitude and latitude fields in the Geolocation field)?  e.g.

```
    $node=Node::create(
      'title'=>'Shop 1'
      'Geolocation field'=>array ('latitude'=>'1', 'longitude'=>'2.33'),
    );
```

An approach such as the one above does not appear to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty straight forward just had to change the field names to correspond with the field names used by Geolocation:

```
$node=Node::create(
  'type' => 'content type - machine name',
  'title' => 'Shop 1',
  'geolocation_field' => ['lat'=> 1, 'lng' => 2.33]
);
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid);
//set value for body field
$node->body->value = 'body';
$node->body->format = 'full_html';

//save value for geolocation field.
//field_geolocation will be your field machine name
$node->field_geolocation = ['lat'=> 12, 'lng' => 2.33];
//save to update node
$node->save();
```